# talend - jasper tJasperReportExec not working on linux

Tags: jasper-reports, talend

I am using TOS Talend. I have a job wherein I am using tJasperReportExec. The job runs for the email IDs list that comes out from a database table and sends out the report output in excel format to each email ID.

The job design is as shown below

tmysqlinput -- > tflowtoiterate --> tJasperReportExec --> tsendMail
tmysqlConnection

The job runs just fine in Windows. However when I run the job on linux , it throws the error

```
*Exception in component tJasperReportExec_1 (burstreports)
java.lang.Exception: No Connection or JRDataSource available to fill the report
    at de.jlo.talendcomp.jasperreportexec.JasperReportExecuter.fillReport(JasperReportExecuter.java:595)
    at cropin_talend.burstreports_0_1.burstreports.tMysqlInput_1Process(burstreports.java:824)
    at cropin_talend.burstreports_0_1.burstreports.runJobInTOS(burstreports.java:1717)
    at cropin_talend.burstreports_0_1.burstreports.main(burstreports.java:1571)*
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies for the delayed answer

I had to connect the tmssqlconnection on subjobok to the rest of the job. This worked .

tmssqlconnection --> onsubjobok -->tmysqlinput -- > tflowtoiterate --> tJasperReportExec

Thanks